# Domain Migration SharePoint Users Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, migration

There is currently a domain migration happening within our organisation.  The users accounts are being migrated from a sub-domain to top level domain.

As part of this we have two SharePoint Farms - but our main SharePoint environment resides in the top level domain.

How can I migrate the users profiles in both SharePoint environments so that they will all work with same permissions/groups/etc. in the main SharePoint Farm in our top level domain.

My preference is to script this using Powershell if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look a [Move-SPUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx) to see if that works for you.

Here is the example from TechNet

```
Move-SPUser -Identity "DomainA\JaneDoe" -NewAlias "DomainB\JaneDoe"
```

Just be careful of your service accounts when scripting it.

Comment: Should this be run only on the SharePoint servers in the destination domain?

Comment: You run it against the web application in the destination domain after you move it over. You could run it at source but probably users would lose access at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add - 
You can use

> $farm.MigrateGroup($*.oldlogin, $*.newlogin)

to migrate AD groups. 
Here are references to few PowerShell scripts to automate your migration process. You can use an input CSV file to do the migration.

Good luck - hope this helps!

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2012/01/07/migrate-users-groups-powershell-script.aspx
- http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/migrate-sharepoint-users-from-one-domain-to-another.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the STSADM command for that:

```
STSADM.EXE -o migrateuser -oldlogin “i:0#.w|SourceDomain\OldUser151” -newlogin “i:0#.w|TargetDomain\NewUser151” -ignoresidhistory
```

The following article describes the SharePoint user migration process in more detail.

https://medium.com/@huptdawas/migrate-sharepoint-userprofiles-from-one-domain-to-another-4b2e45e3ccdb